# Взвешенная диаграмма Вороного

Tags: c++

По заданным точкам, нужно получить диаграмму Вороного где размеры полигонов пропорциональны весу точек.
Я использую для этого следующую формулу:
**Взвешенное расстояние = Евклидова метрика / Вес;**

Дальше по этому минимальному расстоянию, отношу каждую координату к точке полигона Вороного.
Затем я использую релаксацию Ллойда - нахожу центроид каждого полигона (сумма всех координат полигона/количество координат).
И заново строю по центроидам диаграмму Вороного.

Независимо от количества итераций. Получаю не совсем точный результат, мне хотелось бы что отклонение от желаемой площади полигона было не больше 10%.

**Пример 1(5 итераций)**:
Результат таблицей: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmncu.png 
Результат графически: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С каждой начальной итерацией процент отклонения площади уменьшается.
Но затем останавливается и не изменяется.
Если в этом пример сделать 10 итераций, то останется один полигон с отклонением 20%, что в принципе приемлемо, но хотелось бы большего.

**Пример 2(5 итераций):**
Результат таблицей: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2FvU.png 
Результат графически:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь все гораздо хуже, даже 100 итераций не дают желаемого результата - у некоторых полигонов отклонение площади и 40%, и 50%.

**Что нужно изменить в алгоритме чтобы получить желаемый результат?**

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что входные данные могут быть такими, что желаемый результат в принципе недостижим? Т.е. точка с большим весом может быть плотно окружена точками с малыми весами, и т.о. ее полигон не может стать больше, чем доступное пространство до точек с малыми весами.

Comment: Ситуация по входным данным следующая: их дает внешний алгоритм, по которому нет исходников. Но известно следующее: точки имеют набор связей с другими точками, алгоритм старается расположить эти точки, с учетом связей, максимизировав прилегание связных точек друг с другом. Также при их расположении вес учитывается в качестве радиуса полигона (при первичном расположении точек каждый будущий полигон, вначале формируется как круг). Т.е. теоретически такая ситуация возможна, но кажется все-таки должна быть редка. В идеале, сделать свой алгоритм расположения, но это очень нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Вы сможете добавить в вопрос визуальное представление проблемы и правильного и неправильного решения?

Comment: Добавил. Выделил зоны с наибольшим и наименьшим процентом отклонения площади полигона. Пример 2 самый наглядный т.к. в нем одинаковые веса, а значит все полигоны должны быть одной площади.

Comment: Для наглядности, в примере 2, добавил проценты отклонения по всем зонам. Возможно вы и правы. Но я думал, что релаксация Ллойда поможет в этом случае, может быть есть более подходящий алгоритм сдвига точек.